# Why if $a > 0$ , $\lim((e^a)^n) = +\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to + \infty} x^a = + \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

Let $ x^a$, $a > 0$.

$f(x)=x^a$ is increasing

Considering the sequence in $(0,\infty) $:

$$a_n = e^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

We know that: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n) = \infty$$

Since $a > 0$ then:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^a =\lim_{n\to \infty}((e^a)^n) = +\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to + \infty} x^a = + \infty
$$

Note: $e^a \ge e^0 = 1$ $ $ since $ $ $a > 0$

What is the reason for this last implication?

Comment: Note that what is shown here is that the particular choice of $x_n$ = $e^n$ gives us $\underset{ n \to \infty}{\lim} { (x_n)^a} = \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^a = \lim_{n\to \infty}((e^a)^n)=\lim((e^n)^a) =\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(e^n))= +\infty  
 $$
And you have $f$ increasing.
 For every $M>0$ $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $f(e^n)>M$ and $f$ increasing gives $f(x)>M,\forall x>e^{N+1}$

So you have
$$  \lim_{x\to + \infty} x^a = + \infty $$